# Generating random numbers in Simulink with MATLAB function-block

Tags: matlab, random, simulink, matlab-coder

I've tried to both google this question and search among the questions and answers here, but I've found no definitve answer to my question so I'm making a new one. Hopefully it won't be too much trouble!

I'm creating a simulation in Simulink where I have a "MATLAB function"-block that is supposed to take input from another source (we can consider this source a "Constant"-block) and then apply a random number that is generated from the MATLAB function-block on the input.

My problem is that I get the exact same randomized numbers every single time I run the Simulink simulation. And I was wondering if someone could help me solve my problem?

Here is the code (not all of it, but all of it that matters):

```
% function MC_output = randomizer(Stat_input)
%#codegen    minrand = 0.1;
    maxrand = 1.9;
    points = 10;    
    rand_numbers = Stat_input*minrand + rand(1, points).*(maxrand-minrand);
    MC_output = mean(rand_numbers);
end
```

I've read about this solution:

```
coder.extrinsic('rng');
rng('shuffle');
```

I've used it in different ways but with no success. Some help would be greatly appriciated! Oh, and btw, I'm using MATLAB R2012a.

Thanks in advance, Niklas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rand being called from your MATLAB Fcn Block is not the same rand as would be called from MATLAB, hence the reason why `rng('shuffle');` has no effect on Simulink's random number generation.

You could force the MATLAB Fcn Block to use MATLAB's rand function by doing the equivalent to,

```
function y = fcn
%#codegen
coder.extrinsic('rand','rng');
y = 0;

persistent atTime0
if isempty(atTime0)
    rng('shuffle');
    atTime0 = false;
end

y = rand;
```

Or you can use the old style method for resetting the random number's seed

```
function y = fcn(seed)
%#codegen

persistent atTime0
if isempty(atTime0)
    rand('seed',seed);
    atTime0 = false;
end

y = rand;
```

But the easier approach is to feed the random number/vector in as an input generated by the [Uniform Random Number Generator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/uniformrandomnumber.html) block, with its *seed* parameter being set randomly (using MATLAB's rand function).